# How to check if a specific key exists in a specific node in Firebase real-time database with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check if a specific key exists in a specific node in Firebase real-time database with flutter. Code:

```
var pSnapshot = FirebaseDatabase.instance
                            .reference()
                            .child('Parents')
                            .child(currentUId)
                            .key;
                        if (pSnapshot == currentUId) {
                          print(pSnapshot);
                          print(currentUId);
                          print("Key & UID Match in Parents");
                          // redirect to Parents
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  ParentProfile(),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
```

I stored each user under a key which is also their user id when they register.

What I'm trying to do is to say if the current logged in user's id exists as a key in 'Parents', then that means that user is a parent, and therefore I will redirect them to parent page.

This doesn't work, any idea how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not reading anything from the database yet.

The only way to check if a value exists at a path, is to read the data at that path from the database (for example, by calling [`once()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/once.html) and then checking if the [snapshot has a value](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/value.html).

From an existing project of mine:

```
var snapshot = await _db.child("accessTokens").child(token).once();
if (snapshot.value != null) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to be able to access .value on snapshot. I am using this code as you put it here. Any idea how to access the key if that record exists?

Comment: That seems unexpected. Note that I got this code from an existing project where I use it to check if a value exists in the database. Can you edit your question to show what you've done with this code?

Comment: If you look at the updated code, because .value wasn't available so I went back .key. However, where I print pSnapshot and currentUId(the logged in user's id), I get both as the same value. This happens even if I don't have that user in 'Parents' database. The query returns that user id even if it doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: is there a function on that can be applied to the query, say like .once, that checks to see if that specific field exists in the database?

Comment: You're still not reading the data from the database. Without the first line of my code, you won't get a snapshot, and can't check its value indeed. Something like `var pSnapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
                            .reference()
                            .child('Parents')
                            .child(currentUId).once()`

Comment: Any update here @Zaykahal? Did you add the call to `once()` so that you're actually reading the data form the database?

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes, thank you so much, I called .once() and it worked, However I had to put everything you said inside a function and call the function. Again thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and got aroud it, this was my resolution,
I was trying to store extra user info whenever a user signs in, but then i needed to check if the user id exists and then if the user exists then move to homepage, if the user doesnt exist then create the user info, this is the code doing the checks

```
Future getUserInRtdb() async {
    var snapshot =
        await rootRef.child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).once();
    print(snapshot.snapshot.exists); 
    // this print statement returns false if the child is not found
    // returns true if the child is found
  }
```

using this in a future builder does the checks pretty well